# iTunes - reset sync settings on device

Tags: macos, ios, itunes, data-synchronization

I'm running

- iTunes 12.9.5.5 on macOS 10.14.6
- iOS 12.4 on iPhone 8

How do I reset the sync settings on iPhone?

What I have tried:

- General > Reset > Reset All settings (this doesn't reset the sync settings to iTunes.)

Comment: sync settings back to iCloud? or sync automatically over wifi or sync content preferences?

Comment: Not syncing to iCloud this is all local syncing only.  Yes i'm aware of the syncing option but there seems to be a problem where the automatically backup option goes to iCloud and not "This computer" and no matter how many times I select "this computer" and click "sync" or "apply" it reverts back to iCloud backup.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was the following:

Summary:

- iTunes Backup changes to "iCloud" when "This Computer" is selected when iPhone is connected to iTunes.

Issue:

- when connecting to iTunes in iPhone(YourIphone) > Summary > Backups the "iCloud" option was checked.  When I had set the "This computer" option. So when I set it again to "This computer" option and clicked "apply" and "sync" it would backup locally but then revert back to the "iCloud" option.  I thought the settings were corrupted locally. so was looking a way to reset the sync settings to clear out this issue.

Fix:

- on your Device > Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > iCloud Backup > Turn on iCloud Backup (since it was off) > then Turn off iCloud Backup. Reconnect the Device to the computer.  Your settings will now remain on "This computer".

So I'm leaving this solution that took me over 5 hrs to figure out to save other people some time if this ever happens to someone else.

Hope it helps someone else